# Django signals not working, tried every possible solution

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

**signals.py**

```
@receiver(user_logged_in, sender=User)
def when_user_logs_in(sender, request, **kwargs):
    print('user_logs_signal is called')
    LoggedInUser.objects.get_or_create(user=kwargs.get('user'))

@receiver(user_logged_out, sender=User)
def when_user_logs_out(sender, request, **kwargs):
    print('user logs out signal iscalled')
    LoggedInUser.objects.get_or_create(user=kwargs.get('user')).delete()
```

**models.py**

```
class LoggedInUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='logged_in_user', on_delete =models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    session_key = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

**apps.py**

```
class AccountsConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = "django.db.models.BigAutoField"
    name = "accounts"


    def ready(self):
        import accounts.signals
```

I have done anything that i found to solve signals now working but it didnt solve  i have even added  "accounts.apps.AccountsConfig" in my settings.py but still it not firing i am currently logged_in and using jwt based authentication , needs help

Comment: Remove the `sender=...` part.

Comment: No its not working still

Comment: Like i have a certain api which requires person to be authenticated so for authorization i am adding jwt token in the authorization header of this request, and then i am calling this view but this login signal is  not called

Comment: Please help me i am really stuck here i dont know why signals are not working

Comment: Does user_logged_in signal doesnt work for token based authentication